# What is the meaning of the symbol $\ni$?

Tags: notation, definition

I was solving an inequality problem. Just like we write our answer in the form $x\in (a, b)$, I was just wondering if we can write it like $(a, b) \ni x$. Does it make any sense? I've not seen such notation in book or anywhere but got it on my own.

Can anyone tell me what's the use of this symbol and is writing $(a, b) \ni x$ valid?

Comment: What you say, sounds quite right.

Comment: This is correct use of that notation. It does get used sometimes (but less often than $\in$) if the grammar of the sentence makes more sense to mention the set before the element, eg "... the set $X\ni x$ contains the element $x$..." instead of "...the element $x\in X$ contained in the set $X$..."

Comment: The layout of the diagrams I draw on the black/whiteboard while teaching occasionally force me to use $A\ni x$ instead of $x\in A$. In case of emergency I need to draw one of the symbols on top of the other and, consequently, also need to use the version rotated by 90 degrees (one way or the other).

Comment: Yes. $x\in y$ is equivalent to $y\ni x$, in the very same way that $x<y$ is equivalent to $y>x$. In Wikipedia's [glossary of mathematical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_mathematical_symbols#Set_theory) $\ni$ is not (yet) mentioned, but the similar $\supset$ is.

Comment: A way to deduce the meaning of that notation is to confront it with the two (way more common) writings: "$x>0$", "$0<x$". The symbols $>$ and $<$ are used in this context in the very same way the symbols $\in$ and $\ni$ are used in your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing $x\in X$ and $X\ni x$ are logically equivalent, but we use one of them depending if we know the set $X$ and want to claim that an element $x$ belongs to the set or we know the element $x$ and we are claiming that a set $X$ contains that element.

As an example, take the case when $x$ is a point and $X$ is a line. If we write $x\in X$ we say the point $x$ lies on the line $X$, on the other case, when we write $X\ni x$  we say the line $X$ goes through the point $x$. That is, on the first case we know the line and we claim that a point belong to the line, on the second case we know the point and we claim that a line goes through that point.

Comment: Perfectly explained, Thanks a ton!! :D

Answer (score 2):

$\ni$ is very valid, although not as commonly used as $\in$. One could certainly write something like

> Take a real number $x$ and an open interval $(a,b)\ni x$.

It would be really strange to say

> Take a real number $x$ and an open interval $x\in (a,b)$.

because grammatically it looks like $x$ is this interval. I think most people go for

> Take a real number $x$ and an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $x\in (a,b)$.

which is more correct than option number 2, but significantly longer than option 1. I prefer the first one personally, although some times I go for option 3 anyways to conform to the more common phrasing.

Comment: @Anonymous "contains" or "containing" would probably be a decent general reading.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question and responses, that I am unfamiliar with.  I was taught that $\ni$, which is the `$\ni$` symbol, represents "such that".

For example

$~\exists x \in \Bbb{R} \ni x > 0$

would be read as

There exists a value $x$ that is an element of the Real Numbers 
such that $x$ is greater than $0$.